# What are my chances at being hired back at my previous organization?

Tags: company-culture, resignation

2 months ago I was working on some technology for a pretty long time at my previous organization lets call it A.

Now a new Organization B which is a start up, but offered me a great position, better pay, says it's a product development company and even were gonna send me overseas.

Now organization A at the very last week of my noticed period gave me a better, but slightly lesser designation, better pay from Organization B and  the work culture in organization A is simply awesome but I think The CEO of the company was really disappointed.

The manager and Hr from Organization A used all tactics and nearly begged me to stay, but seeing what Organization B had to offer I left. I think I left on good terms, they even said I am welcome to join them again.

2 days into my new job at Organization B and I realize it horrible, they are not a product development company also they expect a guy to work 12-16 hours a day. I have no choice but to quit this new place.

I contacted both the HR and that Manager at Organization A to see if they still have that offer to me,  The manager said If I left the new job I should make sure I am not involved in any legal loophole that could be harmful.

Based on what I described what are my chances of being hired at my previous organization?

Comment: This seems highly localized, only you could possibly know the answer.  In your last paragraph, A appears to be happy to have you back assuming that you haven't created any legal issues for yourself.  If you're concerned about whether or not you've created legal issues, consult a lawyer.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I haven't yet left B but I am going to.

Comment: I am not sure about the legality, I did read the documents. It said that since B paid my salary and if I left I need to server my notice period of 2 months or pay the 2 months salary so maybe the loophole would be if I didn't accept the salary from them I would be safe. Also I did read cases people leave an organization in few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your description of the situation, I think your chances are pretty good.  They obviously wanted to keep you, and it's very unlikely that they have filled your position yet.

I have been in this exact position before.  Years ago, I left a long-time employer for another position.  They tried mightily to keep me, but I was ready for a change.  I realized after a few days that I had made a terrible mistake, approached my former manager, and managed to get my old job back.  I happily worked there for several more years without any long-term consequences.

My advice: be very up-front with them that you made a mistake and realized it almost immediately.   Show some humility and let them know that you see this as a learning experience.  That's your best bet for success.

Comment: I want to mark this as the accepted answer so badly, but I want to read more answers. Thanks buddy for the words of encouragement.